# Magento and recursion

Tags: magento, recursion

I've spent a good couple of hours on this and could use a second pair of eyes.  I'm using Magento and want to print a 'text hierarchy' of categories.  Something like:

```
Default Category > Weightlifting Bars & Plates > Bars
```

My text is duplicating.  Here is what my breakdown should look like

category_name (top_category, sub_category1, sub_sub_category1, sub_sub_sub_category3, etc.)

Here is what I have:

```
    Default Category (Default Category)
    Weightlifting Bars & Plates (Default Category > Weightlifting Bars & Plates)
        Bars (Default Category > Weightlifting Bars & Plates > Bars)
            Men's 20kg Bars (Default Category > Weightlifting Bars & Plates > Bars > Men's 20kg Bars)
            Women's 15kg Bars (Default Category > Weightlifting Bars & Plates > Bars > Men's 20kg Bars > Women's 15kg Bars)
            Junior 10k Bars (Default Category > Weightlifting Bars & Plates > Bars > Men's 20kg Bars > Women's 15kg Bars > Junior 10k Bars)
            Technique Bars (Default Category > Weightlifting Bars & Plates > Bars > Men's 20kg Bars > Women's 15kg Bars > Junior 10k Bars > Technique Bars)
```

Notice it starts duplicating after "Men's 20kg Bars."  That is because the variable doesn't get reset.

Here is my code:

```
function print_tree($tree, $level, $category, $root_id, $print_category) {
    $r = $root_id;
    $cat = $category;
    $level++;

    foreach($tree as $item) {
        if ( $item['name'] == "Default Category" || $r != '' ) {
            if ($level == 1) {
                $cat = $item['name'];
            }
            else {
                $cat .= " &gt; " . $item['name'];
            }

            $parent_id = ($r != '' ? $r : $item['category_id']);
            echo str_repeat("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;", $level) . $item['name'] . " (" . $cat . ")<br/>";

            $this->print_tree(
                $item['children'],
                $level,
                $cat,
                $parent_id,
                $print_category
            );
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

And what calls it:

```
$string = Mage::helper('googlemerchant/data')->print_tree($tree['children'], 0, 'Default Category', 0, $cat->getName());
```

Pay no attention to $print_category.  It is a variable I'm using for some other use.
I know its a logic error, not a Magento error.  The code works fine.

Appreciate the help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to fix $new_cat (formerly $cat).

```
    function print_tree($tree, $level, $category, $root_id, $print_category) {
    $r = $root_id;
    $old_cat = $category;
    $new_cat = $category;
    $level++;

    foreach($tree as $item) {
        if ( $item['name'] == "Default Category" || $r != '' ) {
            if ($level == 1) {
                $new_cat = $item['name'];
            }
            else {
                $new_cat = $old_cat . " &gt; " . $item['name'];
            }

            $parent_id = ($r != '' ? $r : $item['category_id']);

            if ( count($item['children']) != 0 ) {
                echo "level " . $level . str_repeat("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;", $level) . $item['name'] . " (" . $old_cat . ") <br/>";
                $this->print_tree(
                    $item['children'],
                    $level,
                    $new_cat,
                    $parent_id,
                    $print_category
                );
            }
            else {
                echo "level " . $level . str_repeat("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;", $level) . $item['name'] . " (" . $old_cat . ")<br/>";
                $this->print_tree(
                    $item['children'],
                    $level,
                    $old_cat,
                    $parent_id,
                    $print_category
                );
            }
        }
    }

    return;
}
```